# How to run setUp function once per class in Laravel 8 tests?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-8

I would like to run the setUP function just once in a class so all the tests can use the same information since it is read only.

Example: I have my API and in a class I want to test an enpoint that requires an authentication token.For obtaining the authentication token I need to create a user, make the login, and save the token so it can be used to test the endpoint. Right now with the setUp funciton the user is created for each test it would be enough to do it once and share the same token among all the tests. Additionally I am using the RefreshDatabase trait to keep the database clean but I want it as well to run only once per class.

Here I leave a sample code. createUser and loginUser are not implemented here.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Tests\TestUtils;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    const  TEST_ENDPOINT = '/myendpoint';

    private string $token;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        createUser();
        $this->token = loginUser(); //runs for every test
    }

    public function test_endpoint_INVALID_AUTHORIZATION()
    {
        $response = $this->post(self::TEST_ENDPOINT);
        $response->assertStatus(400);
    }

    /*

    ... other tests

    */

    public function test_endpoint_SUCCESS()
    {
        $headers = TestUtils::createHeadersWithBearerToken($this->token);
        $response = $this->withHeaders($headers)
                        ->post(self::TEST_ENDPOINT);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

PHPUnit has a method that can be used, it'll be run before the first assertion is done and before the `setUp` method, and is ran only once per class.

```php
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        # code...
    }
}
```

Something to note is that `setUpBeforeClass()` is a static method. I think a common use case for it is to set reused class properties to stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Because it's static, `$this` isn't available of course, so an alternative is to use `self::$myProp = 'my value';` instead.

There's some more info written about it on the PHPUnit documentation for [Sharing Fixtures](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.6/fixtures.html#sharing-fixture).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

When the `setUpBeforeClass` method is called, the application is not yet bootstrapped, so you will not be able to access the features associated with using models and factories. Instead, you can make the `$token` property static and add a check in the `setUp` method to see if it has any value and, if so, skip reinitializing it.

Also, if you want to authorize a user inside the test, you don't have to get the token yourself. Instead, you can use the `actingAs` helper method. For example:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    const TEST_ENDPOINT = '/myendpoint';

    private static $user;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        if (!self::$user) {
            self::$user = createUser();
        }
    }

    public function test_endpoint_INVALID_AUTHORIZATION()
    {
        $response = $this->post(self::TEST_ENDPOINT);
        $response->assertStatus(400);
    }

    // other tests...

    public function test_endpoint_SUCCESS()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs(self::$user)->post(self::TEST_ENDPOINT);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

See for details [Session / Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication) section.